# How to fix "IntPointField" error while creating document, after upgrading to solr 6.6.5?

Tags: solr

I have upgraded to a solr 6.6.5 version and changed therefore the "lucene match version" accordingly. This apparently is bringing some challenges.

Solr has trouble in building the index, complaining:

```
Error creating document : SolrInputDocument(fields: [sqm=0,&#8203; partner_id=0,&#8203; price=7.5,&#8203; 
...
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=209860] Error adding field 'price'='7.5' msg=For input string: "7.5"
```

The field type is defined as:

```
<fieldType name="price" class="solr.IntPointField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

Error msg:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7.5"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IntPointField.createField(IntPointField.java:181)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.PointField.createFields(PointField.java:216)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addField(DocumentBuilder.java:72)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:179)
```

What needs to be changed regarding the price type, in order to match the given solr version?

Comment: So do you want to only store integers, or do you want to store floating point numbers (which you are submitting)? Are you OK with the data loss?

Comment: I want to show only integers, but with a dot as a thousand sepperator. e.g. 1.000 is 1K

Comment: Are you saying previous it was working fine and Solr keeping value like 1.000

Comment: Then it wasn't an integer field - it was a string field. If you want to still use it as a string field, define it as such. In the best case it was stored internally as `1`, while returning `1.000` as the stored value. If you want an integer field, you'll have to send a plain integer. Format conversion / number formatting should happen in your frontend.