# Solr 7 to 8 migration leads to schema issues - Solr Exception adding field

Tags: solr

I am migrating a very old app from solr 7.7.1 to solr 8.11.2 and do face import problems. The importer is processing the documents but it is not saving any.

The log states:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=893609] Error adding field 'price'='40000.0' msg=For input string: "40000.0"
```

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<schema name="project_name" version="1.5">

    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

    <types>
        <fieldType name="price" class="solr.IntPointField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" docValues="true"/>
    </types>
    
    <fields>
        <field name="price" type="price" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false"  />   
    </fields>

</schema>
```

solrconfig.xml has this entry:

```
<luceneMatchVersion>6.6.5</luceneMatchVersion>
```

I also just realised that I had the same issue when migrating a few years ago to a higher version. Unfortunatelly the solution is not documented but the current prod system runs on 7.7.1 with the same code base as the one I am facing issues:
[How to fix "IntPointField" error while creating document, after upgrading to solr 6.6.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050450/how-to-fix-intpointfield-error-while-creating-document-after-upgrading-to-sol)

Did I miss any configuration settings while installing solr or has something changed that requires a schema update?

Comment: `40000.0` isn't an integer value, so it's complaining about the `.0` part?

Comment: Looks strange, however the SQL does not return an integer and I also figured that I did face some similar issues 4 years ago. Have a look at the updated question please for details. The intpointfield adds a point as a thousand seperator.